# Обработка нажатия клавиш

Tags: c#, клавиатура

Не работает данный код. Жму на любые символы, программа не закрывается.

```
private void textBox2_KeyDown_1(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (!(e.KeyCode >= 0 && e.KeyCode <= 9))
    {
        // Display a pop-up Help topic to assist the user.
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: не пробовали использовать [Keys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.aspx)?

Comment: Так я так и делаю, ребят. Нажатия на F1, Shift, и тому подобные работают. А мой пример -- нет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if (!(e.KeyCode >= Keys.D0 && e.KeyCode <= Keys.D9))`

Comment: Спасибо, котик! Как тут плюсы-то раздавать? Я тут недавно.